# SQLite rank() over partition by support in c# System.Data.SQLite and Mono.Data.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, mono, partition-by

I am using sqlite in one of my application. I need to use rank() over partition by. I am using System.Data.SQLite provider. Does it support rank and other window functions? I am getting error while using this. Its showing

SQL logic error near "(": syntax error

I also need to use this in Xamarin iOS project. Need to know whether Mono.Data.SQLite supports windows functions or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to include the SQL Statement in your question so it can be reviewed, otherwise look at the SQLite railroad diagrams for Windows funcs: https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: If it links against/is compiled with 3.25 or better and the compile time option to disable window functions wasn't used, it should. Most language bindings have a way to get the underlying sqlite version.

Comment: You may assume any simple query like this.

select row_number() over (partition by COLUMN) as row_num
from TABLE_1;

Comment: At this time, last System.Data.SQLite version has been built few months before the release of v3.25 of SQLite (in Sep 2018), which includes the window functions. I've sent a message to the owners of that NuGet package to see when we get a new build.